# What do the numbers in the Top Users section mean?

Tags: support, statistics, top-users

Please refer to the image below.

[image]

I can't seem to correlate any relation between the two numbers. It says I have 222 total score for the jquery tag but how is this evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is the number of upvotes received by the user in non-community wiki situations. The second is number of non-CW answers (or questions in the questions part).

Comment: ah, so the title on the element is wrong.

Comment: cheers weblog             .

Comment: What title are you talking about?

Comment: it says 'total score' when you hover over the number

Comment: Yeah, it's a total score. The total score of that user, for that tag. That's the number of upvotes (probably with downvotes subtracted but I can't confirm or deny this).

Comment: well an upvote is + 10 so the total score is upvotes * 10 surely?

Comment: Just a small correction... the second number appears to be the number of non-wiki answers *that you have earned at least one upvote for*. In other words, it doesn't tally answers with 0 upvotes.

Comment: @redsquare: It's not the rep you have earned from the upvotes, it's the upvotes themselves.

Comment: ok, to me score===rep as we dont really deal with just upvotes anywhere else on the site

Comment: I agree that it's confusing the way it's worded. It's total *upvotes*, not total *score*.

Comment: Total upvotes - total downvotes? e.g. if I have an answer that was upvoted twice but downvoted once, does this count as +2 or +1?

Comment: @Ether: +1, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is votes the second is answers . I believe the votes are a net of upvotes minus downvotes. And I believe the answers may only take into account answers where you received a vote.