# Add a legend to the columns on the "Stats"-tab for a tag

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability, top-users

It took me a long time before I figured out what the two different number columns on [the tag-stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=erlang&sort=stats&pagesize=30) meant. There is also a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/what-do-the-numbers-on-the-stats-tab-mean) about it here on meta.

I suggest that a legend for the columns should be added somewhere on the page, to improve the usability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hover over the numbers, it summarizes at what each number represents. The left column is "total score", which is a value equal to [upvotes - downvotes on all non-CW answers where upvotes > downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-tag-stats-page-calculated/52792#52792). The right column is "number of answers provided", which is the number of answers posted that qualify for your score; it shows how many non-CW questions have positive score.

A legend may help usability better, perhaps. All I know is that the hover is quite consistent with a fair amount of the rest of the numbers on the site. I've never been to that page before, so I just guessed to hover in order to figure what they were.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "total score" is phrased that way because it's the total of upvotes minus downvotes.

Comment: Thanks. I still find it can be a bit confusing. Score just as easily implies votes as it does reputation.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't discovered this.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It may be a bit of an artifact due to Meta discussion about terminology. Maybe my recent [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47234/if-reputation-werent-called-reputation-what-would-you-call-it) should have been a feature request. ;)

Comment: I think it's bad design to rely on tooltips for a page to make sense, and two columns of unlabelled numbers does not make sense.