# How can I view the "hall of fame" page?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation-leagues, top-users

I remember viewing a page having monthly achievers, daily top rankers or something like this. But now I am not able to find a link to that. May be its just in front of me and I am just overlooking it.

Comment: @Ben by the time this question was asked, the reputation league still didn't exist; the OP here referred to the top users of tags, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers

Comment: @sha, the question fairly is generic though and with Jeff's answer covers both bases.

Comment: @Ben OK, I understand what you were trying to do, so having both tags looks like the best bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't have a list of monthly achievers or anything. However, we do have a tag stats page, which lists the top scores in participation in the tags for both question askers and answerers. There is a list for the scores over the course of the last 30 days, and one for overall. You can access these when browsing any tag by clicking the "stats" tab at the top.

An example, for C# on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=stats&pagesize=50

Check out [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-tag-stats-page-calculated/52792#52792) for a look into how score is calculated.

---

Originally, tag stats would allow combinations of tags like [java]+[swing]. This was apparently [never intended and caused problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60857/combo-tag-stats-are-no-longer-available/60868#60868), so the functionality has been removed.

Comment: Yup thats what I was looking at, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for picking a stats page that I'm on!

Comment: Those combined tag stats pages don't work - they just give you the stats for the first tag in the URL.

Comment: Ah, [i see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60857/combo-tag-stats-are-no-longer-available).

Answer (score 8):

Reputation leagues are now rolled out:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Blog entry:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/

Answer (score 2):

Two bits that Grace's answer didn't mention:

- The tag stats without specifying any tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats&pagesize=50
- codeka's monthly league Stack App: http://www.codeka.com.au/Solt/League/SO/2010/7