# Combo Tag Stats are no longer available?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, top-users

At least back when I originally posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57395/how-can-i-view-the-hall-of-fame-kind-of-page-in-stack-overflow/57397#57397), I could look at the stats for participation in certain tag pairs and other groups. But as Georg Fritzsche notes, it only displays the first tag now. In fact, while the URL indicates the combination of tags and also prohibits access to the info page, navigating to another page changes your search to only the first tag.

Are combo tag stats no longer going to be available? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was never intended, and led to some performance problems in extreme cases, so it's been removed.

Tag stats was always meant to be single-tag only.

This functionality is moving to the `/tag/{name}` route soon with some other new tag-based functionality; it doesn't belong on `/questions/` at all.

Comment: While it was interesting while we had it, I had a feeling this was the case. It makes sense, really. Thanks for the quick answer!