# Stack Overflow tag pairings?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does anyone know where I might find data on which tags are often found together on Stack Overflow? I would like to better understand machine learning and was thinking about starting with tag relationships on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd imagine Stack Overflow just shows you in order what it would without any tags for each tab (i.e. Newest, Featured, Votes...). But list only ones containing the selected tab. @admdrew is right, this is more for the meta.

Answer (score 2):

This type of question is part of "meta".  There used to be a similar ability to do this but it was removed as it was considered undesirable.

You can refer to it at [Combo Tag Stats are no longer available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60857/combo-tag-stats-are-no-longer-available/60868#60868)

Alternatively you could try [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and query like this.

[Most Frequently Unanswered Two-Tag Combinations](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69155/most-frequently-unanswered-two-tag-combinations)

Comment: While this question should *be* on `meta`, I don't think `meta`'s tags are really helpful to the poster's question.

Comment: @admdrew I realize that my initial answer was off, do you think this is better?

Comment: Yeah good call, I did not know that before, cool!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [StackExchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are talking about. Just in case I will cover both.

### Tags in the Tags section of the website.

I highly doubt that this is what you are refering to because wel.. it's pretty straight forward.
Tags are sorted by the filter selected above (*popular* by default) which means that they are ordered by the number of time they were used in questions.

> [image]

### Tags in question.

Tags in question totally up to the user (except on Meta where you have mandatory tags) so I don't think they're are specific pairing according to tags but simply popular tags.

Your best shot would be to simply look at the popular tags section, **take the popular ones and run a query in the  [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to see which tags are highly associated with the popular ones.**  (I have no idea what you want to do with this so my answer could be irrelevant to your needs depending on what you are trying to accomplish **exactly**.