# Reputation ranking system?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I view the “hall of fame” page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57395/how-can-i-view-the-hall-of-fame-page)

Would it be good to have a ranking system for say the top 1000/5000 users on SO?

First off I understand that something like this opens the floor up to a whole host of people sad enough to just try and get on the board.

But I feel that it would actually be helpful, because I often find myself looking at popular and high rep users because I know I can learn a lot from their content.

I also understand the philosophy of judging the answer not the answerer but, could it hurt?

What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean something like this - http://stackexchange.com/leagues

Answer (score 4):

Great idea!

In fact, I've used a time machine to implement this in the past. Go find it at https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Why the time machine, you ask? Because I really wanted to compare myself over time and see if I've ever made it to [first place](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-09-09). :-P

Comment: Sorry.... please slap me with a fish

Comment: Here you go: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsfiD78Cy0s

Comment: i would upvote that for hilarity if i could!

Comment: Martijn, I told you not to use the time machine on a day-to-day basis. It creates anomalies in the time vortex. Now [look what you've done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153709/14-7-3-arithmetic-overflow-in-careers-invitation)

Comment: @Pekka: Bugger, I was being so careful too! There are more: [Missing from Month Reputation List](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153184) [Reputation league says I've been a member for 1 year, 12 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81415) [I'm ranked twice in the leagues!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149392) etc. Oops!

Comment: Yeah. Remember what the doc said: *Emergencies only,* man.