# Tag `info` tab show upvoted count different from `stats` tab

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tabs

The tag's `info` tab show upvote count different from the `stats` tab. For instance, in tag [`boost`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=boost&sort=stats&pagesize=50) `stats` tab shows 91 upvotes for all time for me, and `info` tab shows `You were upvoted 94 times on non community-wiki answers with this tag.` Same mismatch in other tags. In `C++` tag I have 1,544 vs 1619 upvotes on these tabs.

Comment: Confirmed. It's slightly off in every tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one in the stats tab is the total score, which is total upvotes minus the downvotes.

Comment: I'll accept this. This behavior is not obvious though.

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between "upvotes" and "score". The stats tab uses a [crazy formula to determine its value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-tag-stats-page-calculated/52792#52792), which is summarized as the "sum of your net score (upvotes - downvotes) on all non-CW posts with a positive net score (upvotes > downvotes)". The info tab just tells you how many upvotes you have, regardless of downvotes.