# Wording in tag mouseover on user page is confusing

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

*A minor quibble* - On the user page, down where it shows the tags in which the user is active, hovering over the number to the left of each tag shows the message "Answered K non-wiki questions with a total score of N."

[image: Confusing mouseover emphasized by freehand circle]

I was perplexed by this, because I equated "score" with "reputation".  After poking around on meta, I figured out this was actually up-votes on non-wiki questions, which makes sense.  Can you change the message to something like "Answered K non-wiki questions with N up-votes." or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might equate "score" with "reputation", but that's not what the system does. Reputation is just reputation, whether you want to call it "points" or "mojo" or "large arbitrary numbers". This is not unlike how one might refer to the conclusion of a question (in getting a good answer) as "closing" the question, whereas the system uses "closing" to refer to something different. Yes, it might be confusing if you interpret it that way, but at the end of the day "closed" still means a question that no longer accepts questions, and the same goes for the meaning of "score" being defined as something that isn't reputation.

*Score* is used to refer to the *number of the upvotes on a post minus the downvotes*. Referring to the displayed number as "upvotes minus downvotes" is pretty bothersome after a while, and we use that value in *a lot* of calculations: [lots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question) [badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) [requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/18/guru), post visibility on the front page, bounty auto-award, deletion prevention, and much more. So a term is very useful to have, and "score" representing the effective value is a fairly appropriate term.

Comment: How about "Answered K non-wiki questions with N net up-votes"?

Comment: @mtrw That's not really accurate and remains misleading. Net upvotes implies that a quantity of upvotes were lost or cancelled. Downvotes reduce post score, but they don't affect the number of upvotes a post has. Moreso confusing with the aforementioned negative profiles - someone who has a -5 in [reputation] didn't get -5 upvotes. As well, there was a point in time which quantity of upvotes *was* used as a metric in other points - the original tag wiki and synonyms had this before switching to use score like everything else.

Comment: Actually, The example you gave about Jeff doesn't add up now. I don't know if they changed things, but he has 142 listed for both lists even though he has a couple of net negative posts.

Comment: @gnostradamus I noticed as I was re-researching, but actually, the negatives *are* included. What changed is the tag stats page. waffles mentioned a long time ago that he was thinking of removing that whole "only positive" element from the tag stats, it seems they've gone and done it at some point.