# Can someone explain how the tag points work?

Tags: support, tags, badges, score

I have a tag that has this information:

`102` TagName **x113**

When I hover over it, it says:

"Asked 12 non-wiki questions with a total score of 64.
Answered 101 non-wiki questions with a total score of 102."

So, what's the x113 ?
How is everything counted (I earned much more than 102 points).

And when will I get the tag badge ?

Comment: 12 + 101 = 251?

Comment: That's real information from my user

Answer (score 9):

The first number is the total score on just the non-wiki *answers* you've given. This number is relevant because it is what is used to determine when you have earned a [tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). Note that this number is the total **score**, not the total amount of Rep you earned. If you had 4 upvotes and a downvote on an answer, it would contribute 3 to your total **score**, but 38 to your total **Rep**.

The second number is the total number of **posts** you've made (questions and answers, wiki and non-wiki) that involved that tag. You appear to have no wiki posts, since 12 questions + 101 answers = 113 posts. I, for example, [currently have 937 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) for the matlab tag, and my hover text tells me I have 1 non-wiki question and 933 non-wiki answers. The three missing wiki answers can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:52738%20%5Bmatlab%5D%20wiki:1).

Answer (score 3):

The first number is [your summed vote score of all non-wiki answers in that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73107/wording-in-tag-mouseover-on-user-page-is-confusing/73116#73116), with the hover clarifying that point. If you hover over it, as you can see, it tells you the breakout of your non-wiki posts in general.

The second number is the number of all questions and answers you have for that tag, regardless of wiki status.

Answer (score 1):

The first number is the score

The second number is the number of question + number of answer.