# How is "Score" determined on a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the 'Score' on the Top Users page calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated)

I know about Reputation, but I am unfamiliar with "Score".

How is score determined?  Does having an accepted answer give you "Score" in a tag?  (It would seem not for me.)

How can you see your "Score" for a tag?

Comment: The tag score is the value explained here: [How is the 'Score' on the Top Users page calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated) The page used to be called "Tag Stats", actually. To save you the navigation time, the value is equal to "The sum of `upvotes - downvotes` on all non-wiki posts where `upvotes > downvotes`".