# How is the Top Answerers Score Calculated?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

I am trying to figure out how the top answerers score is calculated for a given tag. I saw the post below, but when I checked my own score It has a value of 2, but I have 3 Up Votes and No Down Votes. Are the scores only updated periodically?

[How is the 'Score' on the Top Users page calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated/52792#52792)

Comment: They only get updated once a day. So you'll have to wait.

Comment: Thanks that does answer the question. I kept searching for "Top Answerers Score" and I wasn't getting any hits.