# maximum daily reputation and top users score

Tags: support, reputation, top-users, tag-score

If I get 30 upvote in answers with a particular tag, does it calculate 30 score for me in top users section  or just 20 score ? ( considering maximum daily reputation of 200 for upvotes )

Comment: Tag scores aren't capped.

Comment: I didn't understood what you meant,sorry, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Looks like a diamond moderator specifically notes [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52792/189840) in the comments that all votes are taken into account, regardless of whether you've hit the cap.

Comment: Im really sorry, but what does **cap** means ?

Comment: Ah sorry. By "cap" I mean the daily reputation limit. Do you want me to pull out the relevant comments into an answer here?

Comment: Well, [this kind of proves](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/topusers) what @Dennis said - 117 score for answer posted two days ago. :)

Comment: another question, when exactly in day will top users list update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I'll go ahead and pull out my comment into an answer.

As noted in the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52792/189840):

> @yes Only upvotes and downvotes, and only the corresponding score. It
>   has no effect to or from reputation, so things such as votes that give
>   no reputation due to the reputation cap, they still count. –  Grace
>   Note ♦ Jun 1 '11 at 18:19

and a little further down

> @yes123 Score is not derived from reputation, as mentioned in my
>   previous comment, so it is not affected by the reputation cap. – 
>   Grace Note♦ Jun 2 '11 at 15:07

Plus, as @ShadowWizard notes, @Gamemorize's score on English Language & Usage in the "phrase-requests" tag, as shown [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/topusers), is currently 117 (and will be 150+ once it updates again), but the only post with a nonzero score was made just two days ago.

This pretty much definitively shows that the Top Users score is *not* affected by the daily reputation limit.

Comment: so, I got my answer earlier in comments, but as you are the only answerer here, I gonna accept yours ;), thank you

Comment: another question, when exactly in day will top users list update?