# Gold badges for tags

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

I'm curious how the count works for upvotes when determining badges for tags.  According to the greasemonkey script that got passed around here on meta, I have surpassed 1000 votes in the [php] tag on SO (also on the [PHP stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=php&sort=stats&pagesize=50)).  This happened about 4 or 5 days ago.  No sign of a gold badge for it yet though, and I'm pretty sure I can't be in debt for a tag badge.  Are downvotes considered as a negative against the total upvotes for badge calculations?  Is it a weekly batch job?

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Adding the 'bug' tag, as no one seems to have an answer and it doesn't appear to be intended behaviour.  Also, [others seem to be encountering this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48075/tag-gold-badge-not-awarded).

Comment: Whether downvotes count against your badge or not, the score shown on the tag stats page is the net amount of upvotes minus downvotes, so you clearly do have 1000+ votes.

Comment: I have no idea, but congrats on 1000 votes in `[php]`! :)

Comment: @ccornet - ah, interesting.  I don't spend much time going over the stats or mulling over badges, so I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: I blame society. Clearly that's to blame for your lack of badge.

Comment: Well CW answers don't count, I'm just not sure if they're reflected in the count on the tag stats page.

Comment: [According to Welbog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/what-do-the-numbers-on-the-stats-tab-mean/3301#3301), the tag stats only reflect votes in non-CW situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somebody added some "security" to our scheduled tasks, which caused them not to run on SO.

Fixed.

Comment: Hah, "security".  Around here all you need is some sparkly avatar images to distract everyone.  I'd go for the "obscurity" approach, maybe with waffles.  Thanks for the fix.