# Tag gold badge not awarded

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gold badges for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48023/gold-badges-for-tags)

According to the [ladder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=stats), I've gotten 1100+ votes in [java] tag, and yet I still have yet to be awarded the gold badge for [java] category. Is this a bug, or have I not met the qualification somehow?

Also, can someone also check if I've qualified for Electorate yet? Because I admit that I've been disproportionately upvoting questions instead of answers to skew my ratio towards it (a known side effect of the badge, the way I understand it), and I think I *should've* qualified for it now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48023/gold-badges-for-tags

Comment: I guess, you just need to wait, those tag based badge take several days.

Comment: @S.Mark - is that the "official" answer?

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/when-are-topic-badges-awarded

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen the stats page in a while. It's kind of depressing now... I should have taken a screenshot while I was #2.